# Epoch & Unix Timestamp Conversion in PHP and mysql is not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, google-api

1473424835535

http://www.epochconverter.com/

using this which gives exact date

**Result : GMT: Fri, 09 Sep 2016 12:40:35.535 GMT**

but in PHP

```
$returnValue = date('d.m.Y H:i:s', 1473424835535);

Result : 22.12.48660 05:32:15
```

tried in mysql also

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME('1473424835535', '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s %x')
```

not working

**Note :** *This record is migrated from google api*

How to rectify this issue or any method to rectify this issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: milliseconds !== seconds: `echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s', (int) 1473424835535/1000);`

Comment: hi Mark Baker Please post as a solution i am endorsing your comment , your comment a solution which i am looking

Answer (score 1):

Your timestamp seems to be in **milliseconds**, while both php's and MySQL timestamp implementations work on a **seconds** basis. Solution: divide your timestamp by 1000:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(1473424835535/1000,'%Y-%M-%d %H:%i:%s %f')
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the very site you linked to:

> Assuming that this timestamp is in milliseconds

The PHP and MySQL manual states that the timestamp they take is "seconds since Unix epoch".

A quick way to determine whether or not you have a valid timestamp, as defined by the manual, is to count the number of digits. Abovementioned site has a common timestamp listed as well, which you can use for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

FROM_UNIXTIME(1473424835535/1000,'%Y-%M-%d %H:%i:%s %f')  is the way os selecting from Mysql and

Proper PHP Way is echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s', (int) 1473424835535/1000);

Thanks for [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker) and [Shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5389997/shadow)